# How to prove that $f(x)$ has a multiple root in $Q$ if and only if $disc(f) =0$

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $f(x) = x^3 +ax+b$ contained in $Q[x]$ prove that $f(x)$ has a multiple root in $Q$ if and only if $disc(f) =0$

This is what I've so far since $f(x) = (x-A_1)(x-A_2)(x-A_3), A_1,A_2, A_3$ are roots of $f(x)$ and $discriminant(f) = (A_1-A_2)(A_1-A_3)(A_2-A_3)$. We prove that $f(x)$ has multiple root if and only if $disc(f(x))=0$.

$(=>)$;Assume $f(x)=0$ has a multiple root, so at least 2 roots are same WLOG, $A_1 =A_2$ then this gives $disc(f)=0$

$(<=)$;Assume $disc(f(x))=0$, so $(A_1-A_2)^2(A_1-A_3)^2(A_2-A_3)^2 =0$,  $R =0$-divisior-free this gives one of the factor is zero. Then f(x) has a multiple roots.

Am I doing this proof right? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant of a polynomial f(x) is (up to a scaling factor depending on the leading coefficient) defined to be
$$ \prod_{i<j}(r_i-r_j)^2 $$
where the $r_i$ are the roots of $f(x)$ in some splitting field. It's clear from this definition that the discriminant vanishes if and only if $f$ has a multiple root.

Comment: If "multiple root in $\Bbb Q$" means "multiple *rational* root" then the claim is obviously false. =)

Comment: True, I missed that part.